# Can I Make One-side/Two-side Video Call To An Android Phone Using HotSpot Or Within A WiFi network (without internet charges)

Tags: applications, wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, video-calling

File Transfer Apps like Shareit can transfer files with both methods:

1.With Mobile Hotspot (without internet)

2.Through WiFi Router when both phones connected with same (without internet)

Is there any Android App available to make video call to another android device  without internet charges (through phone hotspot or same WiFi router with no internet)?

Comment: Are you strictly looking for one that does video calls only or maybe just calling as an allternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching around on the internet I found two apps, one called `WalkieTooth` and another called `Atasoy LANPhone`.

## [WalkieTooth](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.masmil.walkietooth&hl=en)

WalkieTooth allows video and audio chat over WiFi, WiFi Hotspots, Bluetooth and WiFi Direct. To set it up:

1. [Download from Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.masmil.walkietooth&hl=en) on both devices
2. Select the Camera icon on both devices
3. On the first device select 'Server', under 'WiFi'
4. On the second device select 'Client', under 'WiFi' and input the IP address displayed on the first.
5. You should now be in a video call, press the camera icon to turn on your camera

> Walkietooth allows to establish a full duplex communication channel between two Android devices, letting them to communicate for all the time needed, better than having two walkie talkies.

## Atasoy LANPhone

1. Download the APK from the ['official' site](http://www.atasoyweb.net/lanphone-android/en/downloadlanphone.php)
2. Install the APK by opening it (You may need to enable '*Unknown Sources*' in <kbd>Settings > Security</kbd> first)
3. Open the app and press the menu button on the navigation bar
4. Select '*Settings*' to open the settings page
5. Find the option named '*Camera*' and choose which camera you want to use
6. Repeat process on other device and press <kbd>Menu > Refresh List</kbd> to scan for devices

**Screenshots:**
    [image: 4]] [image: 5]]

For just WiFi chat, files and *audio calls*, then these apps support it:

- [Wi-Fi Talkie FREE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.remaller.android.wifitalkie_lite)
- [BlueFi Phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.okean.btcom)